# Entity Framework 7 + IDbCommandInterceptor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core

In version 7 of EF you can use the interceptor?
In releases prior to their .NET 5 interface (IDbCommandInterceptor) was located in: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception, but in .NET MVC 5 and 6 no.

Answer (score 0):

EF7 does not yet provide such feature "out of the box". The feature is currently (ver. 1.1) on their backlog. See: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap